# Ĉu ekzistas komunumo en StackExchange kie oni nur parolas esperante?

Tags: movado

Ĉi tie, oni ofte parolas angle, kun demandoj pri la esperanta lingvo. Mi pensas, ke gravas ekzisti komunumon kie oni nur parolas esperante. Ĉu ĝi ekzistas?

Comment: Laŭ mia modesta kompreno S.E. origine estas anglalingva projekto (kial ekz-e mi mem kutime demandas Angle ĉi tie). Tio kompreneble estas malavantaĝo por homoj kiuj ne regas la Anglan. Aliflanke, milionoj da homoj kiuj jes regas la Anglan sed ne Esperanton, havas tie ĉi aliron al informoj pri Esperanto. Miaopinie, tio estas bona maniero ”malfermi” Esperanton al la ekstera mondo (aŭ sufiĉe granda parto de ĝi). Pure esperantlingva S.E. atingus malpli da homoj (sed verŝajne pli da aktivaj esperantistoj…)

Comment: PS Esperantlingva retejo simila al S.E. certe estas brila idea! :-)

Comment: Mi komprenas vian logikon. Bedaŭrinde, ŝajne via logiko estas ĝusta.

Comment: Mi scivolas cxu tiu cxi demando ne estas pli tauxga por la "meta" grupo... sed jen interesa diskuto (en la angla) pri simila temo. https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/language-of-esperanto-stackexchange-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bedaŭrinde tio ne ekzistas kaj mi dubas ke ĝi iam povus ekzisti. Ĉiu komunumo de StackExchange devas trapasi striktan procedon antaŭ ol esti aprobita kaj komunumoj en aliaj lingvoj estas aparte limigitaj. Kvankam ekzistas kelkaj komunumoj en ne-anglaj lingvoj (ekzemple la [portugala StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)), ili iam decidis ke ili [ne plu kreos novajn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).

Tamen ekzistas aliaj rimedoj por demandi en Esperanto. Notindaj estas [Reddit](https://reddit.com/r/esperante), [KioTio](https://kiotio.com/) kaj [Telegram](https://www.telegramo.org/).

Comment: Ni aldonu ke oni certe jam rajtas starigi demandojn en Esperanto en Esperanto Stack Exchange.