# Ĉu eblas subjekto kun infinitivo?

Tags: infinitive, subject

En [alia demando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/%C4%88u-ekzistas-komunumo-en-stackexchange-kie-oni-nur-parolas-esperante), unu uzanto skribis la jenan frazon:

> Mi pensas, ke gravas ekzisti komunumon kie oni nur parolas esperante

Mi kredas ke tio ne estas gramatike ĝusta, ĉar *ekzisti* ne povas havi objekton. Ĉu eblus simple forigi la akuzativon de *komunumon* por ke la infinitivo *ekzisti* rekte havu subjekton kiel ĉi tio:

> … gravas ekzisti komunumo …

aŭ ĉu necesas vortumi ĝin alimaniere?

Comment: Vi certe pravas pri la gramatika eraro pri "komunumon".

Answer (score 3):

La frazo sendube estas malbona pro diversaj kaŭzoj, sed certe povas esti infinitiva subjekto. Tio estis la temo de [tiu fadeno](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/can-infinitives-be-subjects) en kiu ankaŭ vi respondis.

La problemo ne estas la infinitivo...

- Gravas havi bonan gramatikon.

Mi pensas ke la problemo estas semantika. Oni povas diri ke ekzisto gravas, sed la senso de la frazo ne estas ke ekzisto gravas, sed ke la komunumo ekzistu. Tial la verbo estu en la u-formo en la fina frazo.

- Gravas, ke ekzistu komunumo kie oni parolas Esperanton.

Mi kredas ke mi iomete miskomprenis vian demandon, ĉar mi vortumus ĝin jene: Ĉu eblas infinitivo kun subjekto?